# Is it ok to move the page-title outside of the content div? Or is there a better way?

Tags: theming

I've got a couple of blocks which I would like to appear above the main content area on one particular page...
These two blocks are sitting above 'Main page content' blocks in admin/structure/block.

After enabling the page titles to be displayed, I realised that this isn't going to work, because I still want the page title to be displayed ABOVE these two blocks. So in between these two blocks and the main page content.

Is it ok for me to modify the template so that the page-title is outside of the content div? Or is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Blockify module](http://drupal.org/project/blockify). It will create block for a lot of common drupal elements (including page title), so you can easily place them on a page with a UI, rather than hacking templates.

Comment: Thank you!!! Sounds perfect. The only thing is... The page title is now being displayed 3 times... in the main content area...

Comment: I removed the following code from node.tpl.php

  <?php if ($title): ?>
    <h1 class="title" id="page-title">
      <?php print $title; ?>
    </h1>
  <?php endif; ?>

Which has removed the extra page-title instances....

However, because I am now using h1 for page-title the "Welcome to " text is appearing on the homepage again. I had originally hidden it by display: none...

Comment: Duh!!!
Because it is now a block I can hide it from the homepage!!

Thank you!!!